# Livepatch shutting down the entire User runtime, just to check for patches

Tags: networking, docker, canonical-livepatch, ubuntu-pro

After enabling Ubuntu Pro,
I have been noticing my services were going down randomly.

after investigating, it turns out the Docker rootless service is being shutdown by Livepatch.
it looks like Livepatch will stop the entire non-root user session, just check for patches.

why is this happening?, and can i limit Livepatch to only stop services when there is a patch? or run at a certain time?

I followed the quick setup guide in the forums:
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-pro-beta-tutorial/31018
and setup rootless docker using the offical repos.

I don't think i faced the same issue when testing with docker running as root.

Livepatch logs:

```
Oct 22 20:48:59 server canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd[626]: Client information is recent, not refreshing.
Oct 22 21:45:16 server canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd[626]: Client information is recent, not refreshing.
Oct 22 22:40:26 server canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd[626]: Client information is recent, not refreshing.
```

Syslogs:
(notice how it took 20 minutes from the runtime shutdown to livepatch to answer with `not refreshing` and start everthing up again)

```
Oct 22 21:17:01 server CRON[21339]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Oct 22 21:21:52 server systemd[1]: session-70.scope: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 22 21:21:52 server systemd[1]: session-70.scope: Consumed 1.035s CPU time.
Oct 22 21:22:02 server systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 1000...
Oct 22 21:22:02 server systemd[20525]: Stopping libcontainer container 35f885360294c71ffb8bbf7abd60573f6326c3932b49e0c154b109c7c24f13c8...
Oct 22 21:22:02 server systemd[20525]: Stopping libcontainer container 6c5c11a84ec88d046d69cc74f570ab90be7d629b5e0311a1f13052ac8b0ea819...
Oct 22 21:22:02 server systemd[20525]: Stopping libcontainer container 8269a937c9065c37667713326dc77aa77d2c24015bda1eae700514384232fadb...
Oct 22 21:22:02 server systemd[20525]: Stopping libcontainer container 9ab8f94852ccc241c0245cfb63c39ec2a37be80b72d2c3696485eddc3ec4498b...
Oct 22 21:22:02 server systemd[20525]: Stopped target Main User Target.
Oct 22 21:22:02 server systemd[20525]: Stopping D-Bus User Message Bus...
Oct 22 21:22:02 server dockerd-rootless.sh[20582]: time="2022-10-22T21:22:02.421447703Z" level=info msg="Processing signal 'terminated'"
Oct 22 21:22:02 server systemd[20525]: Stopping Docker Application Container Engine (Rootless)...
Oct 22 21:22:02 server systemd[20525]: Stopped D-Bus User Message Bus.
Oct 22 21:22:02 server systemd[20525]: Stopped libcontainer container 6c5c11a84ec88d046d69cc74f570ab90be7d629b5e0311a1f13052ac8b0ea819.
Oct 22 21:22:02 server dockerd-rootless.sh[20582]: time="2022-10-22T21:22:02.472094516Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=6c5c11a84ec88d046d69cc74f570ab90be7d629b5e0311a1f13052ac8b0ea819 module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Oct 22 21:22:02 server dockerd-rootless.sh[20598]: time="2022-10-22T21:22:02.472849811Z" level=info msg="shim disconnected" id=6c5c11a84ec88d046d69cc74f570ab90be7d629b5e0311a1f13052ac8b0ea819
Oct 22 21:22:02 server dockerd-rootless.sh[20598]: time="2022-10-22T21:22:02.472983028Z" level=warning msg="cleaning up after shim disconnected" id=6c5c11a84ec88d046d69cc74f570ab90be7d629b5e0311a1f13052ac8b0ea819 namespace=moby
Oct 22 21:22:02 server dockerd-rootless.sh[20598]: time="2022-10-22T21:22:02.473005844Z" level=info msg="cleaning up dead shim"
Oct 22 21:22:02 server systemd[20525]: Stopped libcontainer container 35f885360294c71ffb8bbf7abd60573f6326c3932b49e0c154b109c7c24f13c8.
Oct 22 21:22:02 server systemd[20525]: docker-35f885360294c71ffb8bbf7abd60573f6326c3932b49e0c154b109c7c24f13c8.scope: Consumed 3.558s CPU time.
Oct 22 21:22:02 server dockerd-rootless.sh[20598]: time="2022-10-22T21:22:02.511228901Z" level=warning msg="cleanup warnings time=\"2022-10-22T21:22:02Z\" level=info msg=\"starting signal loop\" namespace=moby pid=21372 runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2\n"
Oct 22 21:22:02 server kernel: [157295.944919] br-6c0b88f8ba26: port 1(veth5577bc5) entered disabled state
Oct 22 21:22:02 server kernel: [157295.944987] veth9228e2c: renamed from eth0
Oct 22 21:22:02 server dockerd-rootless.sh[20582]: time="2022-10-22T21:22:02.523744814Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=35f885360294c71ffb8bbf7abd60573f6326c3932b49e0c154b109c7c24f13c8 module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Oct 22 21:22:02 server dockerd-rootless.sh[20598]: time="2022-10-22T21:22:02.525046501Z" level=info msg="shim disconnected" id=35f885360294c71ffb8bbf7abd60573f6326c3932b49e0c154b109c7c24f13c8
Oct 22 21:22:02 server dockerd-rootless.sh[20598]: time="2022-10-22T21:22:02.525292098Z" level=warning msg="cleaning up after shim disconnected" id=35f885360294c71ffb8bbf7abd60573f6326c3932b49e0c154b109c7c24f13c8 namespace=moby
Oct 22 21:22:02 server dockerd-rootless.sh[20598]: time="2022-10-22T21:22:02.525315372Z" level=info msg="cleaning up dead shim"
Oct 22 21:22:02 server dockerd-rootless.sh[20598]: time="2022-10-22T21:22:02.537605236Z" level=warning msg="cleanup warnings time=\"2022-10-22T21:22:02Z\" level=info msg=\"starting signal loop\" namespace=moby pid=21399 runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2\n"
Oct 22 21:22:02 server kernel: [157295.975720] br-f1f18b1986ab: port 1(veth3c2f1ae) entered disabled state
Oct 22 21:22:02 server kernel: [157295.975769] veth559746d: renamed from eth0
Oct 22 21:22:02 server kernel: [157296.003871] br-6c0b88f8ba26: port 1(veth5577bc5) entered disabled state
Oct 22 21:22:02 server kernel: [157296.004728] device veth5577bc5 left promiscuous mode
Oct 22 21:22:02 server kernel: [157296.004737] br-6c0b88f8ba26: port 1(veth5577bc5) entered disabled state
Oct 22 21:22:02 server kernel: [157296.040443] br-f1f18b1986ab: port 1(veth3c2f1ae) entered disabled state
Oct 22 21:22:02 server kernel: [157296.041784] device veth3c2f1ae left promiscuous mode
Oct 22 21:22:02 server kernel: [157296.041798] br-f1f18b1986ab: port 1(veth3c2f1ae) entered disabled state
Oct 22 21:22:02 server kernel: [157296.075053] overlayfs: fs on '/home/ftl/.local/share/docker/overlay2/l/TAERJWKUASF2MHUZPFFCHPLTVS' does not support file handles, falling back to xino=off.
Oct 22 21:22:02 server kernel: [157296.077196] br-6c0b88f8ba26: port 1(veth2d92884) entered blocking state
Oct 22 21:22:02 server kernel: [157296.077203] br-6c0b88f8ba26: port 1(veth2d92884) entered disabled state
Oct 22 21:22:02 server kernel: [157296.077298] device veth2d92884 entered promiscuous mode
Oct 22 21:22:02 server kernel: [157296.077418] br-6c0b88f8ba26: port 1(veth2d92884) entered blocking state
Oct 22 21:22:02 server kernel: [157296.077422] br-6c0b88f8ba26: port 1(veth2d92884) entered forwarding state
Oct 22 21:22:02 server systemd[20525]: Stopped libcontainer container 9ab8f94852ccc241c0245cfb63c39ec2a37be80b72d2c3696485eddc3ec4498b.
Oct 22 21:22:02 server systemd[20525]: docker-9ab8f94852ccc241c0245cfb63c39ec2a37be80b72d2c3696485eddc3ec4498b.scope: Consumed 2.693s CPU time.
Oct 22 21:22:02 server dockerd-rootless.sh[20582]: time="2022-10-22T21:22:02.716530097Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=9ab8f94852ccc241c0245cfb63c39ec2a37be80b72d2c3696485eddc3ec4498b module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Oct 22 21:22:02 server dockerd-rootless.sh[20598]: time="2022-10-22T21:22:02.717027184Z" level=info msg="shim disconnected" id=9ab8f94852ccc241c0245cfb63c39ec2a37be80b72d2c3696485eddc3ec4498b
Oct 22 21:22:02 server dockerd-rootless.sh[20598]: time="2022-10-22T21:22:02.717071835Z" level=warning msg="cleaning up after shim disconnected" id=9ab8f94852ccc241c0245cfb63c39ec2a37be80b72d2c3696485eddc3ec4498b namespace=moby
Oct 22 21:22:02 server dockerd-rootless.sh[20598]: time="2022-10-22T21:22:02.717081664Z" level=info msg="cleaning up dead shim"
Oct 22 21:22:02 server dockerd-rootless.sh[20598]: time="2022-10-22T21:22:02.735374132Z" level=warning msg="cleanup warnings time=\"2022-10-22T21:22:02Z\" level=info msg=\"starting signal loop\" namespace=moby pid=21419 runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2\n"
Oct 22 21:22:02 server kernel: [157296.233281] br-6c0b88f8ba26: port 1(veth2d92884) entered disabled state
Oct 22 21:22:02 server kernel: [157296.233592] br-43a6ccd96e0c: port 1(vethfcc4cf7) entered disabled state
Oct 22 21:22:02 server kernel: [157296.233818] vetheb0af2d: renamed from eth0
Oct 22 21:22:02 server kernel: [157296.267904] br-6c0b88f8ba26: port 1(veth2d92884) entered disabled state
Oct 22 21:22:02 server kernel: [157296.269168] device veth2d92884 left promiscuous mode
Oct 22 21:22:02 server kernel: [157296.269182] br-6c0b88f8ba26: port 1(veth2d92884) entered disabled state
Oct 22 21:22:02 server kernel: [157296.300040] br-43a6ccd96e0c: port 1(vethfcc4cf7) entered disabled state
Oct 22 21:22:02 server kernel: [157296.300913] device vethfcc4cf7 left promiscuous mode
Oct 22 21:22:02 server kernel: [157296.300922] br-43a6ccd96e0c: port 1(vethfcc4cf7) entered disabled state
Oct 22 21:22:02 server dockerd-rootless.sh[20582]: time="2022-10-22T21:22:02.888208586Z" level=error msg="6c5c11a84ec88d046d69cc74f570ab90be7d629b5e0311a1f13052ac8b0ea819 cleanup: failed to delete container from containerd: no such container"
Oct 22 21:22:02 server dockerd-rootless.sh[20582]: time="2022-10-22T21:22:02.893512172Z" level=error msg="restartmanger wait error: Could not mount \"/run/user/1000/docker.sock\" to container while the daemon is shutting down"
Oct 22 21:22:02 server dockerd-rootless.sh[20582]: time="2022-10-22T21:22:02.893525173Z" level=error msg="Error sending stop (signal 15) to container" container=6c5c11a84ec88d046d69cc74f570ab90be7d629b5e0311a1f13052ac8b0ea819 error="Container 6c5c11a84ec88d046d69cc74f570ab90be7d629b5e0311a1f13052ac8b0ea819 is not running"
Oct 22 21:22:02 server dockerd-rootless.sh[20582]: time="2022-10-22T21:22:02.893737165Z" level=info msg="Container failed to exit within 2s of signal 15 - using the force" container=6c5c11a84ec88d046d69cc74f570ab90be7d629b5e0311a1f13052ac8b0ea819
Oct 22 21:22:02 server dockerd-rootless.sh[20582]: time="2022-10-22T21:22:02.893799417Z" level=error msg="Error killing the container" container=6c5c11a84ec88d046d69cc74f570ab90be7d629b5e0311a1f13052ac8b0ea819 error="Container 6c5c11a84ec88d046d69cc74f570ab90be7d629b5e0311a1f13052ac8b0ea819 is not running"
Oct 22 21:22:02 server dockerd-rootless.sh[20582]: time="2022-10-22T21:22:02.893834565Z" level=error msg="failed to shut down container" container=6c5c11a84ec88d046d69cc74f570ab90be7d629b5e0311a1f13052ac8b0ea819 error="Failed to stop container 6c5c11a84ec88d046d69cc74f570ab90be7d629b5e0311a1f13052ac8b0ea819 with error: Container 6c5c11a84ec88d046d69cc74f570ab90be7d629b5e0311a1f13052ac8b0ea819 is not running"
Oct 22 21:22:03 server systemd[20525]: Stopped libcontainer container 8269a937c9065c37667713326dc77aa77d2c24015bda1eae700514384232fadb.
Oct 22 21:22:03 server systemd[20525]: docker-8269a937c9065c37667713326dc77aa77d2c24015bda1eae700514384232fadb.scope: Consumed 9.757s CPU time.
Oct 22 21:22:03 server systemd[20525]: Removed slice Slice /user.
Oct 22 21:22:03 server systemd[20525]: user.slice: Consumed 16.217s CPU time.
Oct 22 21:22:03 server dockerd-rootless.sh[20582]: time="2022-10-22T21:22:03.561853619Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=8269a937c9065c37667713326dc77aa77d2c24015bda1eae700514384232fadb module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Oct 22 21:22:03 server dockerd-rootless.sh[20598]: time="2022-10-22T21:22:03.562513641Z" level=info msg="shim disconnected" id=8269a937c9065c37667713326dc77aa77d2c24015bda1eae700514384232fadb
Oct 22 21:22:03 server dockerd-rootless.sh[20598]: time="2022-10-22T21:22:03.562591681Z" level=warning msg="cleaning up after shim disconnected" id=8269a937c9065c37667713326dc77aa77d2c24015bda1eae700514384232fadb namespace=moby
Oct 22 21:22:03 server dockerd-rootless.sh[20598]: time="2022-10-22T21:22:03.562630970Z" level=info msg="cleaning up dead shim"
Oct 22 21:22:03 server dockerd-rootless.sh[20598]: time="2022-10-22T21:22:03.588505610Z" level=warning msg="cleanup warnings time=\"2022-10-22T21:22:03Z\" level=info msg=\"starting signal loop\" namespace=moby pid=21440 runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2\n"
Oct 22 21:22:03 server kernel: [157297.022519] br-f1f18b1986ab: port 2(veth38fc9f3) entered disabled state
Oct 22 21:22:03 server kernel: [157297.022573] vethc8f0ea3: renamed from eth0
Oct 22 21:22:03 server kernel: [157297.066772] br-f1f18b1986ab: port 2(veth38fc9f3) entered disabled state
Oct 22 21:22:03 server kernel: [157297.067494] device veth38fc9f3 left promiscuous mode
Oct 22 21:22:03 server kernel: [157297.067501] br-f1f18b1986ab: port 2(veth38fc9f3) entered disabled state
Oct 22 21:22:03 server kernel: [157297.109055] br-43a6ccd96e0c: port 2(veth992689d) entered disabled state
Oct 22 21:22:03 server kernel: [157297.109212] veth4c59cff: renamed from eth1
Oct 22 21:22:03 server kernel: [157297.160885] br-43a6ccd96e0c: port 2(veth992689d) entered disabled state
Oct 22 21:22:03 server kernel: [157297.161800] device veth992689d left promiscuous mode
Oct 22 21:22:03 server kernel: [157297.161810] br-43a6ccd96e0c: port 2(veth992689d) entered disabled state
Oct 22 21:22:03 server dockerd-rootless.sh[20582]: time="2022-10-22T21:22:03.797241472Z" level=info msg="stopping event stream following graceful shutdown" error="<nil>" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby
Oct 22 21:22:03 server dockerd-rootless.sh[20582]: time="2022-10-22T21:22:03.799032198Z" level=info msg="Daemon shutdown complete"
Oct 22 21:22:03 server dockerd-rootless.sh[20582]: time="2022-10-22T21:22:03.799430835Z" level=info msg="stopping event stream following graceful shutdown" error="context canceled" module=libcontainerd namespace=plugins.moby
Oct 22 21:22:03 server dockerd-rootless.sh[20582]: time="2022-10-22T21:22:03.799474518Z" level=info msg="stopping healthcheck following graceful shutdown" module=libcontainerd
Oct 22 21:22:03 server systemd[20525]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine (Rootless).
Oct 22 21:22:03 server systemd[20525]: docker.service: Consumed 7.416s CPU time.
Oct 22 21:22:03 server systemd[20525]: Stopped target Basic System.
Oct 22 21:22:03 server systemd[20525]: Stopped target Paths.
Oct 22 21:22:03 server systemd[20525]: Stopped target Sockets.
Oct 22 21:22:03 server systemd[20525]: Stopped target Timers.
Oct 22 21:22:03 server systemd[20525]: Closed D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Oct 22 21:22:03 server systemd[20525]: Closed GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
Oct 22 21:22:03 server systemd[20525]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
Oct 22 21:22:03 server systemd[20525]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Oct 22 21:22:03 server systemd[20525]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Oct 22 21:22:03 server systemd[20525]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
Oct 22 21:22:03 server systemd[20525]: Closed debconf communication socket.
Oct 22 21:22:03 server systemd[20525]: Closed REST API socket for snapd user session agent.
Oct 22 21:22:03 server systemd[20525]: Removed slice User Application Slice.
Oct 22 21:22:03 server systemd[20525]: app.slice: Consumed 7.435s CPU time.
Oct 22 21:22:03 server systemd[20525]: Reached target Shutdown.
Oct 22 21:22:03 server systemd[20525]: Finished Exit the Session.
Oct 22 21:22:03 server systemd[20525]: Reached target Exit the Session.
Oct 22 21:22:03 server systemd[1]: user@1000.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 22 21:22:03 server systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 1000.
Oct 22 21:22:03 server systemd[1]: user@1000.service: Consumed 23.788s CPU time.
Oct 22 21:22:03 server systemd[1]: Stopping User Runtime Directory /run/user/1000...
Oct 22 21:22:03 server systemd[1]: run-user-1000.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 22 21:22:03 server systemd[1]: user-runtime-dir@1000.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 22 21:22:03 server systemd[1]: Stopped User Runtime Directory /run/user/1000.
Oct 22 21:22:03 server systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of UID 1000.
Oct 22 21:22:03 server systemd[1]: user-1000.slice: Consumed 24.844s CPU time.
Oct 22 21:45:16 server canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd[626]: Client information is recent, not refreshing.
Oct 22 21:47:27 server systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of UID 1000.
Oct 22 21:47:27 server systemd[1]: Starting User Runtime Directory /run/user/1000...
Oct 22 21:47:27 server systemd[1]: Finished User Runtime Directory /run/user/1000.
Oct 22 21:47:27 server systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 1000...
Oct 22 21:47:27 server systemd[21471]: Queued start job for default target Main User Target.
Oct 22 21:47:27 server systemd[21471]: Created slice User Application Slice.
Oct 22 21:47:27 server systemd[21471]: Reached target Paths.
Oct 22 21:47:27 server systemd[21471]: Reached target Timers.
Oct 22 21:47:27 server systemd[21471]: Starting D-Bus User Message Bus Socket...
```

Comment: Ubuntu Pro is not supported on this site. Only by the maker direct. You can get info and support starting from here. https://ubuntu.com/support

Comment: Ubuntu pro free doesn't include support, so according to ubuntu's guidelines, technical questions should be asked here.

Comment: Not correct live patch and pro questions are off topic here.

Comment: This should be reported as a bug. There's nothing we can do about it here on [ubuntu.se]